# How to create a button to mirror video

Tags: wordpress, vimeo

I need to create a button to mirror a vimeo video and another one to come back to normal view.
I have been trying using
`transform: scaleX(-1)`

but its not working

I will appreciate any help Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `!important` to`transform: scaleX(-1)`. Or,
This Answer might help you but if you want to mirror the Vimeo video then you will have to mirror the whole Vimeo Video iframe.

```html
<iframe id='VimeoVideo' src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/253989945?h=c6db007fe5" width="640" height="360" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; fullscreen; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
<button onclick='document.getElementById("VimeoVideo").style.transform = "scaleX(-1)"'>Mirror Video</button>
<button onclick='document.getElementById("VimeoVideo").style.transform = "scaleX(1)"'>Back To Normal</button>
```

Comment: Thanks soooo much iamabdm!!! It works perfectly :)

Comment: Glad that helped :) Please consider accepting the answer if that solved your problem.